pycharm openpyxl файл в проекте
Могу ли я сохранить файл в папке проекта и открывать его не по полному пути?
Если пишу
wbb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'0.xlsx')
, а файл находится в C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\openpyxel, мне выводит ошибку
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
.

А точно ошибка из-за того что файл не находит, а не из-за того что он "битый"?

Ах да, не открывается. В текстовом виде сохранить, что-ли, так как csv не открыть этой библиотекой.

Для этой библиотеки нужно именно экселем пересохранить в xlsx. Просто переименование с изменением расширения не меняет формат. Для csv используйте модуль csv, например. Либо с помощью pandas, например.
